# Server Error (500)

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend

This is my JS code in my `index.php`:

```
$('#registerForm').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var regusername = $('#register_username').val();
  var regpassword = $('#register_password').val();
  var regemail = $('#register_email').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"register.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{regusername:regusername, regemail:regemail, regpassword: regpassword},
    success:function(data)
    {
      if(data == 'Yes'){
        $('#login').hide();
        location.replace("login.php");
      }
    }
  })
});
});
```

And this is my `register.php` where I update the database :

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST["regusername"]))
{
  $connect = mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", "", "", "" );
  $output = '';
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["regusername"]);
  $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["regemail"]);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["regpassword"]);

  $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email) VALUES('$username', 
  '$password', '$email')";
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
  {
    echo 'Yes';
  }
  $_SESSION["regusername"]=$_POST["regusername"];
}
```

I'm getting a server error in my `register.php` and I can't figure out where.

Also, is it better to use `.serialize()` to send data via AJAX instead of this?

Edit: Fixed `register.php`, thanks. Is it better to use `serialize()` than sending each variable individually?

Comment: where are you getting the error on the clietnside or serverside?

Comment: Edit : Fixed the max stack error, now I'm just getting a server error (500) in my server side.

Comment: Is $connect imported or defined in the file but not included in your post?

Comment: Oh shoot, thanks for that @jbman223, Il fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are referencing the input elements from the dom, not the values.

```
data:{register_username:register_username, register_email:register_email, register_password: register_password}
```

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks!